# probability of selecting a complete team

Tags: probability

A 3-person basketball team consists of a guard, a
forward, and a center.
If a person is chosen at random from each of
three different such teams, what is the probability of selecting a complete team?

The answer to this is $\frac29$ but I don't quite understand why. My approach is somehow like this:

$P$$($selecting whole team$)$$=$$P$$($selecting center$)$$P$$($selecting forward$)$$P$$($selecting guard$)$$=$$\frac39$$\frac38$$\frac37$$=$$\frac{3}
{56}$

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a selection from the first team.  No matter which position you choose, you're still in business.

Now make a selection from the second team.  The probability that you are still in business (because you did not select the same position as you chose from the first team) is $\frac 23$.

Assuming that you're still in business (which happens $\frac 23$ of the time), make a selection from the third team.  The probability that you'll choose the one missing position is $\frac 13$ so the probability that you have chosen a complete team is $\frac 23 \cdot \frac 13 = \frac 29$.

Another way to see this is that there are $3^3=27$ equally likely ways to select one player each from $3$ different teams, and $6$ of those ways result in a complete team, so the probability of success is $\frac {6}{27} = \frac 29$.

Your calculation seems to allow choosing multiple players from any of the three teams, which is contrary to the conditions of the problem.  After making a choice from the first team, you no longer have $8$ candidates to choose from.  You only have $6$.  Also, the first factor of $\frac 39$ imposes the condition that your first choice has to be a center.  It doesn't.  Your first choice can be any position at all.

Comment: okay, thanks for including 2 approaches.